# Does Firebase cache data itself on local storage or just query results? Also, if online, is local DB hit?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time working with a remote database, so bear with me.

I know via the docs that queries using the same syntax will make use of the cache.  Ie: In the following code, if the first query is hit during the remote connection, and connection is broken before the second query executes, the second query will still work via the cache.

```
let scoresRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("scores")
scoresRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryLimitedToLast(4).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print("The \(snapshot.key) dinosaur's score is \(snapshot.value)")
})

scoresRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryLimitedToLast(2).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print("The \(snapshot.key) dinosaur's score is \(snapshot.value)")
})
```

1. Is the data in the document itself cached, causing a query in any form for data already fetched to succeed once offline.  For example if in this example I had a 3rd, offline query that tried to fetch the 4th to last child of scores by its key, would it work via the cache?
2. When remote connection is working, will a FirDataEventType query go straight to the remote, or will a local query be run before a remote is run?

Thank you for any input you have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, the second query will not have to retrieve additional data, since the children have already been retrieved.

But there are many subtleties in play here. And Firebase synchronizes the data when it changes, which allows for even more scenarios.

Instead of trying to imagine all the things that might be happening, it is probably more educational if you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#setloggingenabled). This will show the actual data that is being retrieved by the client for each query.